# AS3 - Finding the Y position of a rotated object if X is known

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to find out the Y position of a rotated object on stage, when only the X position is known. I am not extremely formiliar with how I'd go about doing this, but I know it'll be related to the Rotation of the border object.

What I need to do is know that based on the below X position that is worked out, what the exact maximum Y position can be before it hits the black border that is onscreen. I know that the original position is 280, but I am not sure at all how I then work out what the Y position is further down the line.

I have attached the code to find the X (all be it, it doesn't take into account any rotation as on this level it isn't needed), as well as a screenshot so you can understand clearly.

Thank you for your time.

```
    private function init(e:Event = null):void{
        var maxX:int = stage.width
        var freeSpace:int = 300
        var startX:int = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (maxX - (freeSpace+this.width))) + freeSpace;    
        this.x = startX
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on your question but hopefully these suggestions will help:

- You can use the localToGlobal() function on a display object to return a rotated,  translated, and scaled point within that display container to the stage. Example, $p:Point = myMovieClip.localToGlobal(new Point(10, 10));
- A [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) is also a nice and easy way to rotate a point. Example, var $mtx:Matrix = new Matrix(); $mtx.tx = 10; $mtx.ty = 10; $mtx.rotate(); and now $mtx.tx and $mtx.ty have the rotated result

Those probably won't answer your question, but I figured I'd mention them just in case and before I get into something more complex. Like wvxvw said you can't really solve the equation you're trying to do without some other variables. I wrote some code that shows how to find Y when comparing X to a point in a line segment:

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var $s:Shape = new Shape();
addChild($s);

var borderStart:Point = new Point(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2);
var borderRotation:Number = 45; 
var borderLength:Number = 800;

var borderRad:Number = borderRotation * (Math.PI/180);
var borderEnd:Point = new Point(borderStart.x + Math.cos(borderRad) * borderLength, borderStart.y + Math.sin(borderRad) * borderLength);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, update);

function update(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var $g:Graphics = $s.graphics;
    $g.clear();

    //Drawing the rotated border
    $g.lineStyle(3, 0xff0000, .5);
    $g.moveTo(borderStart.x, borderStart.y);
    $g.lineTo(borderEnd.x, borderEnd.y);

    //Finding if and where mouseX collides with our border
    if (stage.mouseX >= Math.min(borderStart.x, borderEnd.x) && stage.mouseX <= Math.max(borderStart.x, borderEnd.x)){
        var $x:Number = stage.mouseX;

        //SOLVING HERE : Solve collision with X
        var $percent:Number = ($x - borderStart.x)/(borderLength * Math.cos(borderRad));
        var $y:Number = borderStart.y + Math.sin(borderRad) * borderLength * $percent;

        //Drawing to our collision
        $g.lineStyle(1, 0xffff00, .6);
        $g.moveTo($x, 0);
        $g.lineTo($x, $y);
        $g.lineStyle(2, 0xffff00, 1);
        $g.drawCircle($x, $y, 3);

        trace("----\nCollision @\t" + "x: " + $x + "\ty:" + Math.round($y));
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will give some insight on how to solve your particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm answering the right question, because as you worded it, it's impossible to solve, or rather you would have to accept that Y can be just anything... (In order to be able to find a point in a vector space over R^2 you need a basis of two vectors of a form (x,y), but you only have a vector in R^1).

But it looks like you want to find an intersection of the "black line on the screen" - i.e. an arbitrary line and a vertical line through the lowest point of the "shape" which you want to fit. It's hard to tell from the question, what shape are you trying to fit, but if it is a rectangle, which is not rotated, then it would be either its bottom right or bottom left corner. You can then find which point to choose by comparing the angle between a horizontal line and the "black line" and the horizontal line and the bottom of the rectangle.

Next, you would need to find an intersection between these two lines, the formula can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_intersection